# Mysql Insert into with variables

Tags: mysql, insert

Hey i want to write a function in sql which insert the handover parameters.
My Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `p_add_client`(IN p_username VARCHAR(45),IN p_reach VARCHAR(45),IN p_purchase VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
set @str = ('INSERT INTO t_', p_username,'(Purchase,Reach) VALUES (p_purchase,p_reach)');
prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

but it doesnt work. I get the error Code 1064. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `CONCAT()`:

```
set @str = CONCAT('INSERT INTO t_', p_username, '(Purchase, Reach) VALUES (p_purchase, p_reach)');
```

However, you will then get an error when you execute, because the variables are not known.  So, you could write:

```
set @str = CONCAT('INSERT INTO t_', p_username, '(Purchase, Reach) VALUES (p_purchase, p_reach)');

prepare stmt from @str;
execute stmt using p_purchase, p_reach;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Of course, this all suggests a pretty bad database architecture.  Why would you have a separate table per user, rather than rows in a single table for all users?  There are some arcane reasons why this might be a solution to a real problem, but such an approach much more commonly suggests a problem with the solution architecture.

Comment: actually i had only one table. but for 100 clients the table has 1*10^7 rows. so i thougt it is better for the perfomance if every one has his own table. so i have to do check only some thousend rows for a client. is it wrong? on table would be very easyier

Comment: @nicoschuck . . . You want one table with an appropriate index.  If you have ten million rows, you might also want some sort of partitioning scheme.